# Changing response.statuscode for ajax requests raise error "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I am working in an MVC project where user roles, and permissions for each of the action methods are stored in the database. What I want to achieve is to use the authorize filter feature in mvc by overriding **AuthorizeAttribute**. This way I can register my custom authorize filter globally.

Here is what I am trying to do, following [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765891/2098335). I am following [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655086/Handling-authentication-specific-issues-for-AJAX-c) to handle ajax requests.

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
     //Custom permission checking logic 
     return false;//no permission for all methods-Just for testing
}

public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated(filterContext);}
}

private void CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // If Result is null, we’re OK: the user is authenticated and authorized. 
    if (filterContext.Result == null)
        return;

    var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
    var request = httpContext.Request;
    var response = httpContext.Response;

    var user = httpContext.User;
    // If here, you’re getting an HTTP 401 status code. In particular,
    // filterContext.Result is of HttpUnauthorizedResult type. Check Ajax here. 

    if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;//401
        else
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;//403

        response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;

        response.End();// This line is causing the problems

        return;
    }

    if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //Redirect to customerror page
    }
}
```

The issue is when I am calling a method using ajax post, my custom exception filter is catching an error saying **`"Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent "`**
 If I remove response.End(), I am getting a 401 response in the ajax error handler method instead of 403.
 I tried

```
 HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
```

instead of response.end, but then also I am getting 401 error

Is there anyway to avoid this exception?

**Update**
I am using this general error handler method in javascript to catch all ajax request errors ( I need correct status code for response):

```
 function ajaxFailed(xhr, textstatus, errorthrown) {
    debugger;
    if (textstatus == "error") {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            window.location = "/Account/Login";
        }
        if (xhr.status == 403) {
            $("#divoutput").html("you don't have permission.");
        }
    }
    if (xhr.status == 500) {
        $("#divoutput").append("<br/> internal servererror." + xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**
       **My Current Solution:**
   Check the Exception.Message property of the raised exception in my custom exception handler filter and ignore it if the message is :**"Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent "**.

I know this is an inefficient method, but I have no other solution yet. Waiting for a good solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of the handling the request:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated(filterContext);}
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

**Update**:

The article you've linked says that you have to handle **other event handler method** `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
```

Not the `OnAuthorization` as you did.

**Update #2**:
Try to use the buffering output with

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
```

so your server is prevented to send the headers back to the client.

Comment: if (filterContext.Result == null) is always true if I do so.

Comment: THat's because no validation were performed - but the headers were not sent.

Comment: I don't get you. I need to execute base.OnAuthorization(filterContext) first so that user.Identity.IsAuthenticated property will be set correctly. Then in my custom method, I am checking this value to find, whether it is an authentication issue or authorization issue.

Comment: This method is sending the `headers` back to the client. After that you can't change status of the response.

Comment: Try to use `Response.BufferOutput = true;` here, preventing the server send the headers to the client, more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2892633/213550